# Rails 7 importmap leaflet-css images path fix?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, import-maps

##### What I'd like to do:

I would like to have a **leaflet layers control** in my Rails 7 app.

##### What I get:

Leaflet works fine, but the control **appears without the icon**, like this:

[image]

and in the browser console I get this error:

```
GET http://my_ip/trial_models/undefined/layers.png 404 (Not Found)
```

and in my server log the error is presented like this:

```
Started GET "/trial_models/undefined/layers.png" for my_ip at 2022-03-30 06:50:43 +0000
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/trial_models/undefined/layers.png"):
```

I've replaced the actual ip address with "my_ip". The '`undefined`' is really there in the error messages.

##### How I did it:

First I created a Rails 7 app and imported leaflet like this:

```
./bin/importmap pin leaflet
./bin/importmap pin leaflet-css
```

I then created a TrialModel using standard rails g scaffold. I then added the following stimulus div in `trail_models\show.html.erb` :

```
<div data-controller="trialmap" data-trialmap-target="trial" style="height:600px" class="leaflet-container"></div>
```

I created `\app\javascript\controllers\trialmap_controller.js` with the following contents:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import "leaflet-css";

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = [ "trial" ]

    connect(){
        import("leaflet").then( L => {
            this.map = L.map(this.trialTarget).setView([ 51.472814, 7.321673 ], 14);
            var base_map = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> | <a href="https://www.swmmgo.com">SwmmGo</a>',
                transparency: true,
                opacity: 0.5
            }).addTo(this.map);
            var landMap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: 'attributions'});
            var layersControl = new L.Control.Layers({
                "Street Map": base_map,
                "Landscape": landMap
            });
            this.map.addControl(layersControl);
        });
    }

    disconnect(){
        this.map.remove()
    }
}
```

##### What I've explored:

I tried downloading leaflet-css like this:

```
./bin/importmap pin leaflet-css --download
```

but same result.

I can see that there is a references `background-image:url(images/layers.png);` in the imported/ downloaded file `vendor/javascript/leaflet-css.js`. But there doesn't seem be any images folder anywhere like `vendor/javascript/images/` or the like.

The stringify version of `L.Control.prototype.options` is just `{"position":"topright"}`.

I tried setting `L.Control.prototype.options.iconUrl = "layers.png"` (and `"/layers.png"`) in the js controller and then placing a manually downloaded `layers.png` file in public. But this changed neither the results nor the error messages.

##### My questions:

1. How can I get the icon to show and the error to disappear? (a work-around would be ok too)
2. What is the "correct way" to handle assets and asset paths which css files reference when using importmap?

**Any help would be much appreciated!** Thanks!

Comment: I found a workaround. Added the following to application.css: .leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers-toggle { background-image:url(https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/layers.png); width: 44px; height: 44px; }. I would still love to know what the real solution is? (my question 2)

Comment: I tried the above and also tried adding the images to /app/assets/images, /public/image/ and /vendor/images and still get error `Request URL: http://localhost:3000/trials/images/layers-2x.png, 
404 Not Found`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html says `vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins`. Have you found a better way yet?

Comment: Cross-posted by @Greg as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/443852/115

Answer (score 2):

I had similiar problems when using markers, my solution was not using leaflet-css and just using the leaflet CSS from CDN

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I did like Luis - put the leaflet.css downloaded from https://leafletjs.com in vendor/assets/stylesheets and the images in public/images - that solved my issues with broken marker/layer images

Answer (score 0):

Don't use leaflet-css, it bundles both the leaflet css and an ancient version (0.6.4) of the leaflet js code.  It seems that the other answers here are on target - rails importmaps are for js only; if you are working with a third-party lib that has its own css assets you will need to handle those separately either through a CDN or by downloading them and placing them alongside your other css assets.